# how to remove 'any' keyword in generic constraint

Tags: typescript

I have some problems to create a generic function without the `any` keyword which is not recommended by our linter.
I tried to switch it against `unknown`, `never` because I don't really need to know the specific type at. But that just led to different errors.

Of course I could stay with `any` and just disable our linter for that, but I would really like to know if it could be done without it.

Here is the code, very simplified and modified for illustration purposes ([TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZQK4CMBWBTAxvAXzgDMoIQ4ByKAD0wGdKBuAKBeADsZspiBDXNjgARYHwA2EAOYBhCF2xcAPABUAStnqpxMAHyIWcOLkn1sALhQYc+VRq07drAm2KoO+YPLj0AFhAB3UQlpVThsGm4OABN6ETFJWXkomCU+DgBPOAB6ACo4AN8+eFx0uHQhVDNouF8eIU56bj4aiGI4dKzc7N1dAAooTQhxADceSz6ASjgAXn0VSZYEQxzsgDoNlhc2Ez56OIBRGj5wcWxgxLkFLjhQMDOQRRg4i+krlKURiGBo3WWjEwQMyzOAcbABKxYPCpL4-fqTZxsPyBV5SJRHE73c4JN7JJ79KazfRgiEY07YkJJa4wKYIoA)):

```js
interface DialogContent<TResult> {
  close: Subject<TResult>;
}

function showDialog<T extends DialogContent<any /*what can be used here instead of any */>>(resolver: () => T)
{
  //...
}


class ExampleDialogContent implements DialogContent<void>{
  close = new Subject<void>();
}

showDialog<ExampleDialogContent>(() => new ExampleDialogContent());
```

Comment: Can you fix up your showDialog function in the code example above so that it actually compiles?  It's not clear to me what your intent is there.

Comment: you mean to fix tsplayground so it does compile? it compiles if you switch subject import against an empty generic class, but my problem is not compilation. the problem is that our linter does not like any (@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any ['Unexpected any. Specify a different type.'])

Comment: What does that `showDialog` function look like when it compiles successfully but you get the linter error?  We can't work with code that doesn't compile; show us your compiling code having the linter error.

Comment: I dont know what you mean =/ The `showdialog` method does compile like this (without content). I get linter errors in vscode before compilation.

Comment: Oh, I see what you did.  You put a comment inside of a generic type definition.

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe your specific needs outweigh a linter's complaints.  Linters are just advisors, not dictators; if you can't (or don't want to) follow the linter's suggestions, feel free to ignore them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `any` is the right move in your case because no other type would work for creating a type that matches any form of the generic `DialogContent` type.  Your best solution would be to suppress the lint via a comment.